# Motorola Triumph changes Volume between Songs or with Notifications

Tags: media-player, volume-control, motorola-triumph, pandora

I have a VirginMobile Motorola Triumph, stock but rooted.

I listen to music with both Pandora and Google's Play Music app.

When listening to music, the volume has two modes, 'soft', in which all the way down is too quiet and all the way up is too loud, exactly as it should be.  The other setting is loud - just loud.  The first click of 'loud' is enough to hurt my ears.

I can change the volume from 'loud' to 'soft' by playing with the Ring or Alarm volumes (not Media).  They don't have to change, but they have to be altered briefly to 'reset' it back to 'soft'.  Furthurmore, if I receive a notification, text, call, or any other sort of message, the volume becomes 'soft' again.

While listening on 'soft', if the song finishes and naturally continues to the next, the volume will jump to 'loud'.  There are other occasions where it does this as well, but I haven't figured out exactly what they are.

---

[ORIGINAL]:
I have a stock rooted Motorola Triumph (which does not have MotoBlur) with Pandora installed.  Media volume is pretty loud, so I keep it on the first click, always (I also have Audio Manager installed, but this problem was happening prior to installation).

However, when Pandora goes to the next song (either because I skipped, down-thumbed, or just finished the song), the volume gets really loud.  It doubles in volume, if not more!

The weirdest part though is that none of the volume sliders (anywhere!) have changed.  Not one.  Furthermore, altering the Media volume (still on 1st click), has no effect other than to make it even louder.  However, if I alter (or even touch) the Ringer or Notification volumes, the song volume drops to where it was.

I'm tired of changing my volume between every song.  I'm willing to talk to whomever (Motorola, Pandora, Google, etc) in pursuit of a fix.  How can I address this?

Comment: Did you happen to solve the issue somehow? Maybe tried a factory reset (I had a lot of instabilities after rooting of some devices, which were immediately solved by a factory reset)? If so, it would be nice to let others (who might be affected as well, as the upvotes might indicate) know the solution :)

Comment: No, I never found anything.  I found that it's not simply a Pandora issue - the issue affects at least Play Music as well, and who knows what other apps.  To be honest I've quit listening to music on my Android - I'm thinking of getting an iPod... :(

Comment: Known issue with older ROMs on the MT. AFAIK its been fixed, but I've since moved on from the mighty Triumph!

Answer (score 0):

I reccomend you contact the makers of Pandora about this issue, as this looks like an app bug rather than a phone issue.

I would suggest emailing them with as much info as you can possibly fit in.

Another option would be to check the settings in Pandora - you may have missed an important setting that is causing this issue.

Comment: Nope, it's not just Pandora.  The Google Play Music app does it as well.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem on my Optimus V, and according to other users of the ROM, it is specific to the ROM.

Sometimes the volume is max level no matter what. The temporary workaround is to actually turn the volume up all the way, then turn it down. As soon as I hear the volume blasting, I have to go against my intuition to turn the volume down (as it usually is in the lowest setting already) and turn it all the way up, then down.

Try that and see if it solves the symptoms. If so, the developers of your ROM need to fix the underlying bug that causes the volume indicator to be out of sync with the actual volume.